# flutter webview plugin display as high resolution

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I am attempting to create a android application to be installed on a android TV device i manage to display it using `flutter_webview` plugin, but all of the image are blurry and not displayed as its resolution. Any workaround with this problem?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://apple.com",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```